# React.js: How to call hook first before first render?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu using React

I have a JSON response which contains how my menu should look like:

```
[
      { id: 0,
        label: "Dashboard",
        link: "/app/dashboard",
        icon: <HomeIcon /> },
      {
        id: 1,
        label: "Inward",
        link: "/app/inward",
        icon: <InboxIcon />,
        children: [
          { label: "PESONet", link: "/app/inward/pesonet" },
          { label: "PESONet Inquiry", link: "/app/inward/pesonetinquiry" },
          { label: "PDDTS", link: "/app/inward/pddts" },
          { label: "SWIFT", link: "/app/inward/swift" },
          { label: "Philpass", link: "/app/inward/philpass" },
        ],
      }
]
```

I'm able to put this JSON response in the state with this:

Sidebar.js

```
const [sideBar, setSideBar] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const sidebar = customizeSidebar()
    setSideBar(sidebar)
  }, [])
```

The function `customizeSidebar()` can be found in my context:

UserContext.js

```
function customizeSidebar(dispatch, profileId, history){
  ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveSideMenu()
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data
  }).catch((err) => {
    // check first if api is down
  })
}
```

As you can see, whenever I get a response, I return it as well.

Therefore, I can get it in the Sidebar.js.

However, problem arises when render happens first before the useEffect function.

```
const [sideBar, setSideBar] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const sidebar = customizeSidebar()
    setSideBar(sidebar)
  }, [])

return (
 <List className={classes.sidebarList}>
        {sideBar.map(link => (
          <SidebarLink
            key={link.id}
            location={location}
            isSidebarOpened={isSidebarOpened}
            {...link}
          />
        ))}
      </List>
)
```

Already tried using `useLayoutEffect` but render still happens first before my API call and assigning to state.

Is there any way I can do first my API call and assign to state before the first render?

Thank you for those who would help.

Answer (score 0):

the best imo is to do something like this

```
return (
 {sideBar.length&&<List className={classes.sidebarList}>
        {sideBar.map(link => (
          <SidebarLink
            key={link.id}
            location={location}
            isSidebarOpened={isSidebarOpened}
            {...link}
          />
        ))}
      </List>}
)
```

So your sidebar will be rendered only when the sidebar data array is full.

Comment: yes I mistype "sidebar" it should be  "sideBar", I have edited me code. It should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Either you return a placeholder is there is no sidebar data:

```
if (!sideBar.length) {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar-placeholder">
      <Spinner/> || Loading text...
    </div>
  );
}

return (
  <List>...
);
```

Or you wrap your Sidebar inside a provider component, and pass your sidebar configuration as a prop.